# Get all possible distinct triples using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, unique

I have a List contains these values: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}. And I want to be able to retrieve unique combination of three. The result should be like this:

```
{1,2,3}
{1,2,4}
{1,2,5}
{1,2,6}
{1,2,7}
{2,3,4}
{2,3,5}
{2,3,6}
{2,3,7}
{3,4,5}
{3,4,6}
{3,4,7}
{3,4,1}
{4,5,6}
{4,5,7}
{4,5,1}
{4,5,2}
{5,6,7}
{5,6,1}
{5,6,2}
{5,6,3}
```

I already have 2 for loops that able to do this:

```
for (int first = 0; first < test.Count - 2; first++)
{
  int second = first + 1;
  for (int offset = 1; offset < test.Count; offset++)
  {
    int third = (second + offset)%test.Count;
    if(Math.Abs(first - third) < 2)
      continue;
    List<int> temp = new  List<int>();
    temp .Add(test[first]);
    temp .Add(test[second]);
    temp .Add(test[third]);
    result.Add(temp );
  }
}
```

But since I'm learning LINQ, I wonder if there is a smarter way to do this?

Comment: _smarter_ is the wrong adjective, methinks.

Comment: I mean better in term of performance. Also LINQ looks a lot cooler than for loops :)

Comment: @Sajeetharan: That's a different problem. The question you linked to is to find the Cartesian product of multiple sequences with each other; this question is to find the permutations of a particular sequence.

Comment: @EricLippert Yeah, i got it now!

Comment: Tony Dinh, it is confusing to me whether or not you want the permutations to be ordered. I notice that {3, 4, 1} is on the list but not {1, 3, 4}. Is that intentional, and does the order matter, or would {1, 3, 4} be just as good as {3, 4, 1} ?

Comment: @EricLippert order doesnt matter {1,3,4} is considered to be the same as {3,4,1}, {4,3,1}, etc..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I used this question as the subject of a series of articles starting [here](http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/13/producing-combinations-part-one/); I'll go through two slightly different algorithms in that series. Thanks for the great question!

---

The two solutions posted so far are correct but inefficient for the cases where the numbers get large.  The solutions posted so far use the algorithm: first enumerate all the possibilities:

```
{1, 1, 1 }
{1, 1, 2 }, 
{1, 1, 3 }, 
...
{7, 7, 7}
```

And while doing so, filter out any where the second is not larger than the first, and the third is not larger than the second.  This performs 7 x 7 x 7 filtering operations, which is not that many, but if you were trying to get, say, permutations of ten elements from thirty, that's 30 x 30 x 30 x 30 x 30 x 30 x 30 x 30 x 30 x 30, which is rather a lot. You can do better than that.

I would solve this problem as follows. First, produce a data structure which is an efficient *immutable set*.  Let me be very clear what an *immutable set* is, because you are likely not familiar with them.  You normally think of a set as something you add items and remove items from. An immutable set has an `Add` operation but it does not change the set; it gives you back a *new* set which has the added item. The same for removal.

Here is an implementation of an immutable set where the elements are integers from 0 to 31:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System;

// A super-cheap immutable set of integers from 0 to 31 ; 
// just a convenient wrapper around bit operations on an int.
internal struct BitSet : IEnumerable<int>
{
  public static BitSet Empty { get { return default(BitSet); } }
  private readonly int bits;
  private BitSet(int bits) { this.bits = bits; }
  public bool Contains(int item) 
  {
    Debug.Assert(0 <= item && item <= 31); 
    return (bits & (1 << item)) != 0; 
  }
  public BitSet Add(int item) 
  { 
    Debug.Assert(0 <= item && item <= 31); 
    return new BitSet(this.bits | (1 << item)); 
  }
  public BitSet Remove(int item) 
  { 
    Debug.Assert(0 <= item && item <= 31); 
    return new BitSet(this.bits & ~(1 << item)); 
  }
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return this.GetEnumerator(); }
  public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
  {
    for(int item = 0; item < 32; ++item)
      if (this.Contains(item))
        yield return item;
  }
  public override string ToString() 
  {
    return string.Join(",", this);
  }
}
```

Read this code carefully to understand how it works. Again, always remember that **adding an element to this set does not change the set**. It produces **a new set** that has the added item.

OK, now that we've got that, let's consider a more efficient algorithm for producing your permutations.

We will solve the problem recursively. A recursive solution always has the same structure:

- Can we solve a trivial problem?  If so, solve it.
- If not, break the problem down into a number of smaller problems and solve each one.

Let's start with the trivial problems.

Suppose you have a set and you wish to choose *zero* items from it. The answer is clear: there is only one possible permutation with zero elements, and that is the empty set.

Suppose you have a set with n elements in it and you want to choose more than n elements. Clearly there is no solution, not even the empty set.

We have now taken care of the cases where the set is empty or the number of elements chosen is more than the number of elements total, so we must be choosing at least one thing from a set that has at least one thing.

Of the possible permutations, some of them have the first element in them and some of them do not.  Find all the ones that have the first element in them and yield them. We do this by recursing to choose *one fewer* elements on the set that is *missing* the first element.

The ones that do *not* have the first element in them we find by enumerating the permutations of the set *without* the first element.

```
static class Extensions
{
  public static IEnumerable<BitSet> Choose(this BitSet b, int choose)
  {
    if (choose < 0) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    if (choose == 0) 
    { 
      // Choosing zero elements from any set gives the empty set.
      yield return BitSet.Empty; 
    }
    else if (b.Count() >= choose) 
    {
      // We are choosing at least one element from a set that has 
      // a first element. Get the first element, and the set
      // lacking the first element.

      int first = b.First();
      BitSet rest = b.Remove(first);
      // These are the permutations that contain the first element:
      foreach(BitSet r in rest.Choose(choose-1))
        yield return r.Add(first);
      // These are the permutations that do not contain the first element:
      foreach(BitSet r in rest.Choose(choose))
        yield return r;
    }
  }
}
```

Now we can ask the question that you need the answer to:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    BitSet b = BitSet.Empty.Add(1).Add(2).Add(3).Add(4).Add(5).Add(6).Add(7);
    foreach(BitSet result in b.Choose(3))
      Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
}
```

And we're done. We have generated only as many sequences as we actually need. (Though we have done a lot of set operations to get there, but set operations are cheap.) The point here is that understanding how this algorithm works is extremely instructive. Recursive programming on immutable structures is a powerful tool that many professional programmers do not have in their toolbox.

Comment: I'm really impressed by the fact you took the time to write a solution that responds to the op's problem + scales well + can be used in a broader context

Comment: Thanks @Eric for your great answer. I can definitely use this to optimize other parts of my project as well.

One thing that I'd like to clarify the ToString() is not compiled for me. So i have to write a separate function to print out all the positive bit index. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @TonyDinh: You're welcome. Perhaps you are using an older version of the BCL which does not have that overload of `String.Join`; I seem to recall that it is relatively new. Just write your own `ToString`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 7);
var r = from a in data
        from b in data
        from c in data
        where a < b && b < c
        select new {a, b, c};
foreach (var x in r) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", x.a, x.b, x.c);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/VKKPjA)

Edit: Thanks Eric Lippert for simplifying the answer!

Comment: How is joining to yourself on a condition that is always true different from simply doing a select-many query?

Comment: @EricLippert It has a symmetric look.

Comment: I am confused by your comment. How is `from a in data from b in data from c in data where a < b where b < c ...` less "symmetric"?  Your solution is constructing data structures in memory to handle the join unnecessarily.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks! I thought of the other syntax, where it would not be symmetric.

Comment: You're welcome. I note that this query is quite inefficient -- see my answer for some thoughts on that. You could make it moderately more efficient by moving the `where a > b` clause up. `from a in d from b in d where a > b from c in d where c > b select ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
var ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

var permutations = ints.SelectMany(a => ints.Where(b => (b > a)).
                        SelectMany(b => ints.Where(c => (c > b)).
                        Select(c => new { a = a, b = b, c = c })));
```

Comment: This would produce both {1, 2, 3} and {2, 1, 3}, which is not what the original poster wants.

Comment: True, I though the op was looking for all the combinations

Comment: I note that your check `c > a` is redundant to `c > b`.  You have already determined that `b > a` in the first `Where`, so you know that if `c > b` then it must be also greater than `a`.

Comment: @EricLippert You noted right, it was a remainder from my previous code